# How do I declare and use a lot of variables in Python at one time?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am a student doing scientific calculations recently,usually,I use odeint function to solve Differential equations，now I need to solve a differential equation system with 100 variables.If I follow my previous programming style in python,I will act like this:

```
def XFunction(X,t,sets):
   x1,x2,x3,x4,,,,,,x100=X
   lambd=sets
   return np.array([equation1,equation2,equation3,,,,,equation100])
```

But this method takes too long, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use any collection like a list. If you want to have different names for variables then use a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using integer suffixes like that indicates that you probably want to use sequence like a list or array, but a mapping, like a dict could also work. So instead of `x1,x2,x3...`, you write `X[0], X[1], X[2]...` when you need them without pulling them out into locals first. X might already be an array in your program.

If it's just an iterable and not a sequence, you can save it in a list first,

```
X = [*X]
```

Which lets you use the subscript operator `X[i]`.

You don't normally "declare" variables in Python, that's implied by assignment, although you can declare without assignment by giving it a (type) annotation.

The `[equation1, ...]` part could perhaps be done with a *list comprehension*, which is like a mathematical set comprehension, but ordered.

Here's a stupid example with a single map and filter step. (You can have multiple filters or no filters, but you must use at least one loop.)

```
[x**2 for x in X if x % 2 == 0]
```

This list comprehension would generate a list of all squares of the elements of `X` where the element was even.

I don't know what set of formulae you need for your application, but if it can be parameterized by `X`, you can do it this way.